# Arrangement of the first k natural numbers to form a triangle.

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

In the attached images, is there a name for such an arrangement of numbers in mathematics?[Arrangement in twos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlYmP.jpg)

[Arrangement in fours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i09R.jpg)

Comment: The "arrangement in threes" seems to consist of fours.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks